# Clearing value before submitting form (not canceling submit)

Tags: jquery

I want to clear my default value in two input fields before submitting them.
But this don’t work…

```
<form action="page.html" id="myForm">
    <input type="text" value="Firstname" name="firstname" id="firstname">
    <input type="text" value="Lastname" name="lastname" id="lastname">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("myForm").submit(function() {
            if($('#firstname').val() == "Firstname")
                $('#firstname').val() = "";

            if($('#lastname').val() == "Lastname")
                $('#lastname').val() = "";

            return true;    
        });
    });
</script>
```

I don’t want to clear them both on focus.
I cant use html5.

Comment: So you want on focus of the field instead of on submit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

val is a function, you can't use it like this.
Try instead :

```
$('#firstname').val('');
....
```

Comment: There's one more typo, # sign is not added before myForm

Comment: Changed it to `code` <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#myForm").submit(function() {
    var f = $('#firstname').val();
            if(f == "Firstname")
                $('#firstname').val('');

    var L = $('#lastname').val();
            if(L == "Lastname")
                $('#lastname').val('');

            return true;    
        });
    });
</script>
Works!
Cheers

Comment: @soju - yes, it's been added as comment !

Answer (score 1):

Your code is incorrect. You have to use `#` sign before id. So here's it

```
$(function() {  
    $("#myForm").submit(function(e) {       
    e.preventDefault();
        if($('#firstname').val() == "Firstname")
            $('#firstname').val("");

        if($('#lastname').val() == "Lastname")
            $('#lastname').val("");                       
    });
});
```

The line `e.preventDefault();` will stop event propagation to let you see the effect. You can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Call the `val` function with empty string `.val("");`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("myForm").submit(function() {
        if($('#firstname').val() == "Firstname")
            $('#firstname').val(""); // <====

        if($('#lastname').val() == "Lastname")
            $('#lastname').val(""); // <====

        return true;    
    });
});
```

`val()` with empty parameters just return the value of the element.
So your code is equals to

```
if($('#lastname').val() == "Lastname")
    'Lastname' = ""; // Won't change the element value.
```